# $.ajax (post) results in software abort request on the server side

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, jquery

Could someone please help me in identifying what is wrong with the following request. I keep getting software-abort even if on the server side I just return an empty page! That is I don't even read the contents of the post-request. When I send HTTP post request using form post method, instead of ajax, it is all good. So there is no server issue I believe.

Thanks!!

```
         $.ajax({  
               type: 'post',  
               url: "/ajax/feedback",  
               data: JSON.stringify(["Add","1","2"]),  
               contentType: 'application/json',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(resp){  
                 alert("Success. Server said:\n '" + resp + "'");  
               },  
               error: function(e){  
                 alert('There is an Error: ' + e);  
               }  
             });
```

On the server side (python-GAE) all I do is the following:

```
def post(self):
    logging.info('in post REQUEST request handler')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write("received!")
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 222, in handle_request
    self.process_request(request, client_address)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 241, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 254, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2780, in __init__
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 521, in __init__
    self.handle()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 316, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    method()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2794, in do_POST
    self._HandleRequest()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3090, in _HandleRequest
    raise e

error: (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')
```

Comment: What do you mean, "software abort request on the server side"?  What is happening server-side?

Comment: Hi Brad, pls see updated question with server-code and software-abort-error. I am submitting a form whose textarea is named "feedback". But after the abort, there is an automatic get with '?feedback="<whatever-i-enter-in-the-input-box"' appended to the original URL and there is an automatic GET. Not sure why the GET happens (not happening on server side, and ajax code is just what is written above. So not sure who does the GET as well!)

Comment: @dev-vb: deleted my answer. its something else at your server side code.

Comment: no problem. thanks Mithun. I identified the problem though. Sorry the question didn't have the HTML code and complete JS code. Next time, will add all the details. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the answer. Can't believe I spent almost whole day to identify this!

The problem was that I was not returning "false" after intercepting the click on submit button of the html form.

**jQuery code:**

```
$('.submit-feedback > button').click(function(){
    $.ajax(...); // same as in the question above
    return false; // <-- THIS WAS MISSING
});
```

and because of that missing "return false" statement, I was running into all kinds of issues.

**html code:**

```
<form class="submit-feedback">
    <textarea name="feedback" placeholder="add text."></textarea>
    <button>
            Send Feedback
    </button>
</form>
```